# TreeView DoubleClick

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

The tree view in avalonia doesn't have a double-click Event.
Is it possible to implement this in another way?

I want to catch the double-click Event in a ViewModel to execute
a method.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: "I want to catch the double click Event in a viewmodel ".... that isn't what viewmodels are supposed to do

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? can we see some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avalonia uses the UWP naming here (as it does by using `PointerX` events rather than `MouseX` events) and the event is called [`DoubleTapped`](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/bd7877518afb7bff47642eea0e30a299913dd27b/src/Avalonia.Input/InputElement.cs#L284).

Comment: I love the abstraction they've done in UWP. It's a great step into the right direction

Answer (score 1):

`PointerPressed` event [has](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/7b4c10a7f8b03f767da435f052a878dc10593b41/src/Avalonia.Input/PointerEventArgs.cs#L53) `ClickCount` property. Subscribe from codebehind or behavior and check if `ClickCount == 2`

Comment: I tried that, but it´s different to wpf. In wpf the Event is also called when I click the childs (treeviewitems).

Is there an ItemContainerStyle or how is it called in avalonia?